# Разбить текст по нескольким разделителям

Tags: javascript

Есть некоторые слова, по которым надо разбить текст на массив - можно сказать, `split` с несколькими разделителями.

```
reg = new RegExp(['Слово_1', 'Слово_2'].join(' | '), 'i');

res = 'Слово_2 123 Слово_1 456 Слово_1 789 Слово_2 101112'.split(reg);

console.log(reg);
console.log(res);
```

Если разделители в тексте идут не по порядку, то функция отказывается правильно работать. Подскажите, как решить проблему.

https://jsfiddle.net/e2nd0bz5/

Comment: А вы пробелы в регулярку намеренно добавили?

Comment: Наверное, стоит добавить пример желаемого результата.

Comment: Думаю Автор хочет разбить и получить мап ключ значение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let reg = new RegExp(/\s*Слово_1\s*|\s*Слово_2\s*/i);
let res = 'Слово_2 123 Слово_1 456 Слово_1 789 слово_2 101112'.split(reg);

console.log(reg);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, пробелы в регулярке влияют на результат, потому что, например, перед первым разделителем пробела нет, а регулярка его требует.

Можно заменить пробелы упрощённым юникодным вариантом символа `\b`:

```js
const reg = new RegExp(
  ['Слово_1', 'Слово_2']
  .map(word => `(?<!\\p{L})${word}(?!\\p{L})`)
  .join('|'),
'iu');

const res = 'Слово_2 123 Слово_1 456 Слово_1 789 Слово_2 101112'.split(reg);

console.log(reg);
console.log(res);
```